# Expand an AD group inside a collection

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am creating a script that should check the file server for shares, and should list user's that have any kind of access control type (allow / deny) and their rights on the share. I've successfully managed to create collection of objects that have data that I want, but I have issues formatting them in the way I want.

Current situation, how the collection looks like

**Path**     **Identity** **Access** **Rights** 
Share1  User1    Allow     Full Control 
Share1  Group1  Allow     Full Control 
Share2  Group1  Deny     Full Control 
Share2  Group2  Allow     Modify

I am fine with having shares appear in multiple objects, with one identity (user or a group) per object, but I would like to expand groups with its members, when the `$_.Identity` in pipe is a group. But I have issues getting there

My code example is practically non existing, I just tried to check every object in the pipe if it's Identity can be used with `Get-ADGroupMember` but that's it

```
$Collection | ForEachObject { if (Get-ADGroupMember $_.Identity) {Get-ADGroupMember $_.Identity }} ...
```

Desired solution should be like this:

**Path**     **Identity**          **Access** **Rights** 
Share1  User1             Allow     Full Control 
Share1  User1,User2  Allow     Full Control 
Share2  User1,User2  Deny     Full Control 
Share2  User2,User3  Allow     Modify

In this test example, `Group1` is consisted of `User1` and `User2`, while `Group2` is consisted of `User2` and `User3`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not to answer the question but make a suggestion. You should keep the group name in the output as well as the nested users. That way you know where the membership is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I think what I would do is to generate the value on the pipeline like this:

```
$Collection | Select Path,@{l='Identity';e={ if (Get-ADGroupMember $_.Identity) {(Get-ADGroupMember $_.Identity) -join ", "}else{$_.Identity}}},Access,Rights
```

Comment: Sometimes you just pop out of nowhere.

Comment: I've tried this one, it expands groups with their LDAP CN, but for the fields where should be users, it leaves them blank, don't know why when `else` clearly says it should just write Identity from the pipe

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a very similar script.  Rather than bore you with my code, here's where I found assistance in sorting out the nested groups.

[Sort Nested Groups](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/9588.aspx)

Basically, you create a function to get all the group members and then test each item.  If it is a group, call the same function and pass it the newly found group name.

Regarding:

```
$_.identity
```

I used

```
$_.objectclass
```

That will tell you if the get-adgroupmember result is a user or group.  It will error on users, but I just suppress the errors at runtime with

```
$erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"
```

That's probably not best practice, but it works for me.

I tested this with circular nesting and it does not get stuck in an infinite loop.  It actually handled it perfectly by returning the individual results only once.  Probably has to do with safeguards built into windows for cirucular nesting situations.

Some of the info here might be helpful as well:

[Circular Nesting Consequences - ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/351524/what-are-the-consequences-of-an-ad-group-that-has-as-its-member-a-group-that-is)